# OpenGL ES 2.0 Android Application - Conceptual Questions

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm learning OpenGL ES 2.0 for Android with "OpenGL ES 2 for Android" book, from BROTHALER, Kevin. With some others literatures I'm being able to learn OpenGL but on my way I'm having some doubts.

**First question**

Back when I was learning OpenGL 1.0, there was this function "*GLU.glLookAT*" to set the camera's view. ***There is a similar function on OpenGL 2.0?***
I'm aware of the "w" component, ortographic and perspective projection, but I found the *"GLU.glLookAt"* so helpful to my learning that I was wondering if there was anything like that on 2.0.

**Second question**

When dealing with varying colors, I got the code below (in summary):

```
vertexShaderCode = "attribute vec4 a_Position;   " +
                   "attribute vec4 a_Color;      " +
                   "varying vec4 v_Color;        " +

                   "void main(){                 " +
                   "    v_Color = a_Color;       " +
                   "    gl_Position = a_Position;" +
                   "}"


fragmentShaderCode = "precision mediump float;   " +
                     "varying vec4 v_Color;      " +

                     "void main(){               " +
                     "    gl_FragColor = v_Color;" +
                     "}"


... (some code) ...

int a_Position = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(myShaderProgram, "a_Position");
int a_Color = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(myShaderProgram, "a_Color");

GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(a_Color);

GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(a_Position, etc)
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(a_Color, etc)

GLES20.glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

The point I'm trying to make is that I'm telling the attributes "a_Position" and "a_color" where and how they shoud get their information, but what about "v_Color"?

What I understand from this code that the Fragment Shader is receiving information from the Vertex Shader, as the varying "v_Color" was created there, but I thought there was no cross talk between shaders. On the backstage, what's really going on?

And more, the "a_Color" is just there as a "intermediate" attribute. There is no function like:

```
GLES20.glVertexVaryinLocation(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In ES2 you have to define your own matrices and send them to the shader. There are many methods such as LookAt you may usually find them as part of some matrix tools. So in general what you are looking fore are tools to manipulate your matrices usually containing translations, rotations, ortho, frustum, lookAt...
2. Your `v_Color` is much like the `gl_Position` this two will be interpolated and sent to the fragment shader, this is not a "cross talk" as first the vertex shader will complete its work, then the fragment shader will begin having the data received from the vertex shader (oversimplified, try [this](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview)). `varying` is used to send interpolated data to the fragment shader. This means for instance if you ware to draw a line defined by 2 vertices where first had a black colour and the second had a white colour all the pixels in between would be grey creating a smooth linear gradient from black to white. For the more useful case (then the colour) you would do the same with texture coordinates and normals, drawing a quad with texture coordinates from (.0, .0) to (1.0, 1.0) will send you interpolated coordinates in fragment shader so you can directly access the texture, drawing the correct texel. For instance in the middle of the quad the coordinates would be (.5, .5). So `glVertexVaryinLocation` is meaningless since this data depend on very many things such as your buffer resolution, a 4 pixel line would produce 4 unique colour values while 5 pixel line would produce a whole other 5.